# Custom link in 3th level category menu

Tags: magento-1.8, category, magento-community, url-rewrite

I would like to have some custom links in the dropdown menu, but then on the thirth level.

I now have like:

```
RootCategory
-> Category1 (eg Baby)
   -> Gender (eg Boy or Girl)
      -> Kind of clothing (eg trousers, shirts ...)
```

But i want to add an extra 2nd level category "Brands".
On which i want to display some featured brands. 
I also have de Amasty Improved navigation extension, so my brandpages have the following url:  `www.website.com/brand.html`

I would like to have this setup:

```
RootCategory
-> Category1 (eg Baby)
   -> Gender (eg Boy or Girl)
      -> Kind of clothing (eg trousers, shirts ...)
   -> Brands
      -> Featured Brand 1
      -> Featured Brand 2
```

But now they get the url: www.website.com/Category1/Brands/brands.html

*My Question:*
How could i change the link in the navigation to the short url: `www.website.com/brand.html`

I am using Magento 1.8.1 CE

Answer (score 1):

Go into `App/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php` and copy the contents of that file. Now go into `App/code/local/Catalog/Model/Url.php` (create the path if it doesn't exist) and paste the content previously copied.

Now go to function `getCategoryRequestPath` (around line 700) and inside it comment out the following lines:

```
// if (null === $parentPath) {
//    $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
//}
//elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
//}
```

Reindex and it should work.